# Python multiprocessing apply_async read/write var in main process at starting subprocess

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python 3.5 multiprocessing apply_async. My code is like `task = pool.apply_async(myFunc, args)`. I pass a info (object from Info) in the args. It has a data member called startTime. I hope when myFunc starting running, `info.startTime` will be written as `time.time()`. The problem is that the info in main process and the info in subprocess is not the same. `info.startTime = time.time()` in myFunc does not change the info in the main process. Is there a good way to save the startTime? Thanks.

Comment: What about returning `info` so you can access it with `info = task.get()`?

Comment: See [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) for a few solutions

Comment: @Vincent I hope I can get the start time before the subprocess return.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks a lot! I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processes in a pool can not write to a common variable. Think of them as existing in parallel universes. You'll need some mechanism to share information between them. Here's a simple example using `Manager` to keep the time stamp from all the processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, current_process
import time

def do_work(x, ll):
    time.sleep(.2)
    ll.append(current_process().name + ' took task '+str(x)+' at '+str(time.time()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        timestamp = manager.list()
        p = Pool(processes=4)
        for x in range(10):
            p.apply_async(do_work, (x, timestamp))
        p.close()
        p.join()
        print(timestamp)
```

If you change `timestamp = manager.list()` to simply `timestamp = list()`, you'll see it no longer works.

P.S. `Queue` doesn't seem as easy to handle when you're using `Pool`.

Comment: Thanks! I completed the feature by using multiprocessing.Manager.